# Themeing a one to many relationship

Tags: silverstripe

I am developing a one to many relationship in Silverstripe and trying to theme it but I can't get the many part on the page. has_many on the object is defined as:

```
public static $has_many = array(
    'PortsPages' => 'PortsPage'
);
```

and when I try to loop through it using

```
<% loop $PortsPages %>
    <li>$Title</li>
<% end_loop %>
```

only one record comes back (with $Title being nothing - $Name comes back with PortsPage - not the title of the object), despite there being 2 in the database. I believe I'm using version 3.1 and I have gone through http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/tutorials/5-dataobject-relationship-management, which hasn't helped me (and is yet to be updated for the latest version).

### Edit:

The `$has_one` is defined as follows:

```
private static $has_one = array(
    'CityPage' => 'CityPage'
);
```

When I look at the PortsPage table, it appears that the links are in there (there is a CityPageID column that is populated and looks correct). When I look at the PortsPage_Live, The CityPageID column isn't populated.

Comment: it's <% loop $PortsPages %> with an s at the end?

Comment: I had tried that - that produces no li tags (<% loop $PortsPage %> produces 1).

Comment: there being 2 in the database doesn't mean those 2 are actually linked (part of the relation) on your page. Do add the 's'.

Comment: Sorry about the delay in getting back to people. @colymba how can I confirm that the 2 are linked. When I look at the edit page, I can see them in the associated Grid view, and both are published.

Comment: if they show up on the page they should be link. but the best way to debug is to look at the DB table in MySql using phpmyadmin or something else, there should be a `PageID` or some other foreign key on each PortsPage. Also, make sure your PortsPage has the correct reverse `has_one` relation defined otherwise it wont work properly: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/datamodel#has-many

Comment: Thanks @colymba, I've added some more information to the question that hopefully helps get me the answer I need

Comment: Are you publishing the data?

Comment: I thought I had, but I'm guessing you need to re-publish, on every edit (and in the case of links, publish both sides, whereas I think I'd only done one side. I've given full details on my solution below (and upvoted your comments as you lead me there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Cam is the correct programming solution, it turns out my error was in that they weren't linked correctly within the admin side.

While I had selected the Ports from within the city, I was still required to go into each individual port and save and publish them (although I thought I had already published them before linking them).

What tipped me off is that I looked at the CityPageID column in the PortsPage page table was correct, but when I looked at the PortsPage_Live table, the CityPageID column was still 0.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using version 3.1 of SilverStripe you will need to make your static variable "private" not "public".

schellmax is correct in pointing out the missing "s".

$Title will only return something if your DataObject "PortsPage" has that as one of it's object properties.

```
<% loop $PortsPages %>
    <li>$Title</li>
<% end_loop %>
```

Also if your PortsPages in the SiteTree are direct children of the root level page you can access them in the template engine using <% loop Children %>.

Comment: The object PortsPage inherits from Page (and when I look at the page template, it has an element Title). I have set the variables to private, and $PortsPages still returns no entries :-(

Comment: Which pagetype are you trying to create the relationship on? Is it Page has_many PortsPages? The usualy convention in SilverStripe for pagetypes that hold other pagetypes is to name them <PageType>Holder for example PortsHolder. Do you have one of these holders?

Comment: I'm not sure if a holder is the right answer for what I am trying to achieve. Eventually there will be links between ports (in a many to many style) and possibly between cities (one city has many ports).